# Find $\int_{C}\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{x}$ where $C$ is the line from $\left(2,1\right)$ to $\left(4,5\right)$

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Find $\int_{C}\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{x}$ where $C$ is the line from $\left(2,1\right)$ to $\left(4,5\right)$ and $\textbf{F}=6y\textbf{i}+3x\textbf{j}$. I have set the problem up as such:
\begin{align}
\int_C6y\:dx+3x\:dy &=\int_2^4 \left(6\left(2t-3\right)+6t\right)\:dt\\
&=\left[9t^2-18t\right]_2^4\\
&=1296-72.
\end{align}
And please -- no answers, only suggestions since **this is a homework problem**. I'm just trying to see where I may have gone wrong.

Comment: You're missing the multiplication by the norm of the derivative of the parametrization.

Comment: @GitGud Why the norm? My textbook gives $$ \int_C \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}=\int_c \textbf{F}\cdot \frac{d\textbf{r}}{dt}\:dt=\int_a^b\left\langle M,N\right\rangle \cdot\left\langle \frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt}\right\rangle \:dt $$There's nothing about the norm or the derivative there...

Comment: @GitGud Ahh I have figured it out. The answer is $72$. Thanks for your help! I'm not sure where I was integrating wrong, but it's certainly a problem there.

Comment: That formula is for vector fields, for scalar fields see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition) or [this gif](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif).